# Why is a Feistel Network invertible?

Tags: des, feistel-network

[image]
[image]

As it is depicted above, the Feistel Network uses random function fi which is not required to be invertible. However, if fi is not invertible, how can fi(Li) == fi(Ri-1)? Furthermore, why Feistel Network is invertible?

Comment: Draw the full schematic of DES instead and follow the plain/cipher text through it carefully. Function F $\ne$ the whole network.

Comment: TL;DR: the Feistel _structure_ always yields a reversible transformation, regardless of if the _round functions_  $f_i$ are reversible or not. To prove this, use the properties of XOR. It's commutative, associative, and every element is it's own inverse. Also, by definition, a function always has the same output for any given input.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to invert the $f_i$ to invert the whole function.
You know $L_d$, so you know $R_{d-1}$ and the the input of  $f_d$.
The xor can reverse itself. So you get $L_{d-1}$ by simply calculating $R_d$ xor $f_d(L_d))$.
With this steps you just keep going until you know $R_0$ and $L_0$

Answer (score 1):

> how can fi(Li) == fi(Ri-1)

Simply because $L_i = R_{i-1}$. It is clearly visible on your pictures.

Comment: Oh yes, I am so stupid! :(